# How to determine the version of the Gradle Wrapper?

Tags: gradle, gradlew, gradle-wrapper

Gradle Wrapper is typically a small JAR checked into source control, which just downloads the specified version of Gradle and passes commands through to it. Therefore even if you upgrade your Gradle version (either globally on your machine, or locally within your project via `gradle-wrapper.properties`) you are going to have the same Gradle Wrapper version (i.e. the JAR itself is unchanged). Even so, Gradle Wrapper itself is sometimes updated - [in April 2022](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/commit/2ec02f4919c1690debaa604f889f0f0a42dce6a1) for example.

Running `gradlew -version` is going to tell you the version of Gradle within the project, not the Gradle Wrapper version. So how do you determine the Gradle Wrapper version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gradle Wrapper (the jar) does not have any baked-in version information. The closest you can get, is comparing SHA checksum of the jar against [the official list of checksums](https://gradle.org/release-checksums/). It will give you several versions that has same wrapper.

Comment: Thanks! When I run `sha256sum gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` I get e2b82129ab64751fd40437007bd2f7f2afb3c6e41a9198e628650b22d5824a14 which does not match any checksum on that page, does that mean it's not any official version of Gradle Wrapper? Is there any other way to check it?

Comment: There are some guidelines by Gradle team itself here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#wrapper_checksum_verification
Long story short, it can be a non-release version (nighly or release candidate build) or a compromised jar

Comment: It says "Gradle also publishes the checksums of all releases (except for version 3.3 to 4.0.2, which did not generate reproducible JARs)" So maybe the version I have is from 3.3 to 4.0.2. Not sure how I would check that.